# xrdp another xserver might already be active on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

I'm trying to establish a RDP connection from Windows 10 to a Xubuntu 16.04.3 machine through XRDP. I followed this [guide](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10355) with the addition of adding [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hermlnx/+archive/ubuntu/xrdp) so to update the version of XRDP to 0.9.1. 

The major difference from this guide andy my system is that I do not have the option `Sesman-xorgxrdp option` but instead `xorg`.

When I try to connect from my Windows machine I eventually got this error:

[image: RDP error]

`/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` provides me the following information:

[image: sesman-log]

And the corresponding `/var/log/xrdp/log`
[image: xrdplog]

As this [post](https://thornelabs.net/2013/06/28/rhel-6-fix-xrdp-error-another-xserver-is-already-active-on-display-10.html) suggests it could be something to do with system fonts so I implemented this [fontutil.h fix](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10995) without any change.

Could someone please provide with with an fix as google search for 'another Xserver might already be active on display 10' gives me a plethora of possible solutions for which I do not have the time to test.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391164/setting-up-cross-platform-vnc-system/391199#391199) may help you in getting xrdp on Ubuntu16 to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up to get XRDP working since I've found VMware Remote Console which has the same usability, only through an external application. Problem 'solved'.